How to programmatically reboot into Windows 8+'s Advanced Startup Menu?
Although I am able to visit the Boot Manager at boot due to me having multiple Windows boot entries and a significant timeout enabled for the environment when booting:

...I would like to not have to hold Shift when rebooting into it (as the official documentation states):

Entry points into WinRE
Your users can access WinRE features through the Advanced startup menu, which can be launched from Windows in a few different ways: 

From the login screen, click Shutdown, then hold down the Shift key while selecting Restart. 
Click Start > Settings > Update & security > Recovery > under Advanced Startup, click Restart now. 
Boot to recovery media.
Use a hardware recovery button (or button combination) configured by the OEM. 

After any of these actions is performed, all user sessions are signed off and the Advanced startup menu is displayed. If your users select a WinRE feature from this menu, the PC restarts into WinRE and the selected feature is launched. 
WinRE starts automatically after detecting the following issues:

Two consecutive failed attempts to start Windows.
Two consecutive unexpected shutdowns that occur within two minutes of boot completion.
Two consecutive system reboots within two minutes of boot completion.
A Secure Boot error (except for issues related to Bootmgr.efi).
A BitLocker error on touch-only devices.

Advanced startup menu
This menu enables your users to perform these actions:

Start recovery, troubleshooting, and diagnostic tools.
Boot from a device (UEFI only).
Access the Firmware menu (UEFI only). 
Choose which operating system to boot, if multiple operating systems are installed on the PC.


Instead, accessing it would be significantly quicker if I could merely run a .PS1 script as Administrator.

You can probably use bcdedit to accomplish this.

@Ramhound, you may well be correct. I've located https://superuser.com/revisions/1746323/1, which seems like it might work, but as I've asked there, whether it solely applies to the next boot isn't obvious to me. bcdedit /enum FIRMWARE does return a UUID for "Windows Setup" (and multiple "Windows Bootloader" entries) though, so I'm hopeful.

Don’t expect answers to questions asked in the comment section of another question or answer. Especially from an author who is currently suspended. I would spin up a VM, run the command, and see if it accomplishes your desired function

not sure if this one works on Windows 8, but works on 10 and 11: shutdown /fw

@LPChip, that reboots me into my MB's UEFI GUI. You can see that in another question of mine.

I'm sorry, it seems I misunderstood the question.

No worries, @LPChip.

The .PS1 script as would need to have the following command:
shutdown.exe /r /o /f /t 00

The shutdown command is documented here. This was tested to work going back to at least Windows 8.1.

For readers in the future, know that if you dual-boot and use this method, Windows doesn't ever appear to refer to its entry in the UEFI when rebooting. Instead, it always directs the user to the default entry. This matters, because you'll need to manually reboot once into Windows after using this command, because otherwise, you'll boot into whatever is set as the default. The same occurs if you use the "reboot into another operating system" entry in the ADM's GUI.
